# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ObjectParameterError: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file and save it to a mongoose database. however, i keep getting an error
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npwWS.png)
this is the code i am using

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const uuid = require('uuid').v4;
const FileSchema = require('../models/files');
const crypto = require('crypto');

//Set Storage Engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, response, callback) => {
        callback(null, './public/uploads/');
    },
    filename: (request, file, callback) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (error, buf) => {
                if(error){
                    return reject(error);
                }
                const ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
                const id = uuid();
                const filePath = `files/${id}${ext}`;
                FileSchema.create(filePath)
                .then(() => {
                    callback(null, filePath);
                });
            });
        });
    }
});

//init upload
const upload = multer({storage: storage});

router.post('/uploads', upload.array('files'),(req, response) => {
    return response.json({ status: 'OK', uploaded: req.files.length});
});

module.exports = router;
```

please can anyone help?
thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure but you didn't set a function for reject case; in fact you never used variables 'resolve' and 'reject'

Comment: let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve("done");

  reject(new Error("…")); 
});

Comment: @DonDiego i tried what you did but i am still getting the error

Comment: well reading better the error seems it is in file desktop/design/route/file.js at line 23 (not sure for line number because image is cut) Is this that file? Seems that you are passing  in line 23 `FileSchema.create(filePath)`, while that function expects an object

Comment: have a look here, step 8: `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/upload-and-retrieve-image-on-mongodb-using-mongoose/`

Comment: hello i followed the website but a new error has occured saying a function is not defined